# Write fails to NAS drive connected with cifs

Tags: 20.04, permissions, nas

Hello I have serveral NAS hooked up in my network. In fstab they're all setup the same way. Problem is only one I can't write to. My fstab looks like this:

//IPADDRESS/foldername/ /media/foldername   cifs    vers=1.0,username=username,password=password,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nofail 0   0

What can I change to get it so I can wrote to it? I am using a login with those privileges. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by adding in uid=username.